# How to move files from one folder to another folder in file cabinet using suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Want to move files from one folder to another in file cabinet using Suitescript 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load each file using the N/file module. There should be `.setFolder` where you can specify the internal id of the destination folder. After that, save the file.

Comment: Hi Rusty, Thanks for the reply. your suggestion worked for me.
below code is working: 
var fileObj = file.load({
                     id: FileInternalId
                    });
  fileObj.folder = folderId;
 var fileId = fileObj.save();

Comment: Is there any way to copy and paste file from one folder to another ? I don't want to remove files from source folder.

Comment: I would try to load the original file then get the file contents.  Then I would create a new file object, set the contents then save it in a new folder.